# How to turn a dataframe into a dictionary variable and make a barchart from it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I need to convert a data frame query into a dictionary variable but it is saving the STATE and Occurrences as one variable. I need them separate so I can plot a bar chart from it
Am I doing it wrong?

Code for dataframe to dict

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df = df['xyz'].value_counts().to_frame()
df.to_dict('dict')
print (dict)
```

Code i want to use to plot my bar chart

```
data = (dict)
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
plt.bar(range(len(data)),values,tick_label=names)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion convert back to `dictionary` is not necessary, use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html) instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
s = df['STATE'].value_counts()

s.plot.bar()
```

Solution with [`pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

```
plt.bar(range(len(s)),s,tick_label=s.index)
```

EDIT: You are realy close, only remove `to_frame` for convert `Series` to `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
s = df['STATE'].value_counts()

data = s.to_dict()
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
plt.bar(range(len(data)),values,tick_label=names)
plt.show()
```

If want use one column DataFrame add `STATE` before convert to `dict`:

```
df = df['STATE'].value_counts().to_frame()

#select column `STATE`
data = df['STATE'].to_dict('dict')

names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
plt.bar(range(len(data)),values,tick_label=names)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the task i am doing requires me to save the dataframe as a dictionary and construct a plot from the dictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect. How do I go about naming that dictionary?

Comment: @NinJesus - Not sure if underatand, python dict have no name - `{'a':1, 'b':3}` - there are only keys and values

Comment: Ah my bad, I want to name the dictionary state_frequency. Any idea?

Comment: @NinJesus - No, can you explain more? Because dictionary have no name.

Comment: A dictionary variable called state_frequency if that helps

Comment: @NinJesus - I think I know - Change `data = s.to_dict()` to `state_frequency = s.to_dict()`